# Average reponse time is high in Jmeter 3.2 version when compared to the response time from jmeter 2.11 version

Tags: jmeter-3.2

I am executing the same script of REST APIs in both jmeter 2.11 and jmeter 3.2 version at the same time with 5 concurrent threads. Observed that the response time in 3.2 version is higher when compared with 2.11 version.

The reason found is, connect time in jmeter3.2 is ~ 500ms to 1000ms throughout the test. Out of 20 requests for a API, 7 requests have connect time. Remaining requests have connect time 0.

Is there any way to avoid this connect time in jmeter. I read that connect time will be zero after initial hits. Why am I getting connect time through out the test. Note i enabled keep-alive option too.

Comment: Why are you compare old version to older version? You should compare to latest 4.0 and show your problematic request

Comment: It is not just about comparing. I want to understand why the connect time is always shows 400 to 500 ms approx in 3.2 version.